Stuck at loading
I installed some packages on my Ubuntu laptop and updated something.
Then I restarted my computer and I am stuck on boot screen ever since. Tried lot of things can't resolve the issue.
I am on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, kernel is 6.8.0-45-generic i ran sudo apt update and i was trying to install da vinci resolve video editor and it prompted me to install some packages and I installed those packages and restarted my PC. and it wont start ever since. Please Help!
This is what I see:


What packages did you install? What did you update? We can't really help if you don't tell us what you did. Please [edit] your question and tell us what you really did.

I am on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, kernel is 6.8.0-45-generic
i ran sudo apt update
and i was trying to install da vinci resolve video editor and it prompted me to install some packages and I installed those packages and restarted my PC. and it wont start ever since. Please Help!
